# Particle trajectory smoothing: where to do the simulation?

Tags: particles, trajectory

I have a particle system in which I have particles that are moving to a target and the new targets are received via network. The list of new target are some noisy coordinates of a moving target stored in the server that I want to smooth in the client.

For doing the smoothing and the particle I wrote a simple particle engine with standard euler integration model.

So, my pseudo code is something like that:

```
# pseudo code

class Particle:
    def update():
        # do euler motion model integration:
        # if the distance to the target is more than a limit
        # add a new force to the accelleration 
        # seeking the target,
        # and add the accelleration to velocity
        # and velocity to the position

        positionHistory.push_back(position);
        if history.length > historySize :
            history.pop_front()

class ParticleEngine:

    particleById = dict() # an associative array 
                          # where the keys are the id 
                          # and particle istances are sotred as values

    # this method is called each time a new tcp packet is received and parsed
    def setNetTarget(int id, Vec2D new_target):
        particleById[id].setNewTarget(new_target)

    # this method is called each new frame
    def draw():
        for p in particleById.values: 
            p.update()

            beginVertex(LINE_STRIP)
            for v in p.positionHistory:
                vertex(v.x, v.y)
            endVertex()
```

The new target that are arriving are noisy but setting some accelleration/velocity parameters let the particle to have a smoothed trajectories.

But if a particle trajectory is a circle after a while the particle position converge to the center (a normal behaviour of euler integration model).

So I decided to change the simulation and use some other interpolation (spline?) or smooth method (kalman filter?) between the targets. Something like:

```
switch( INTERPOLATION_MODEL ):
    case EULER_MOTION: ...
    case HERMITE_INTERPOLATION: ...
    case SPLINE_INTERPOLATION: ...
    case KALMAN_FILTER_SMOOTHING: ...
```

Now my question: where to write the motion simulation / trajectory interpolation? In the Particle? So I will have some Particle subclass like ParticleEuler, ParticleSpline, ParticleKalman, etc..? Or in the particle engine?

Comment: If you know the source position, the target position, how much time it should take to get to the target, and how much of that time has passed, it's just a simple interpolation in your vertex shader.

Comment: uhh.. i haven't thought about shading.. can you give me some example? anyway there are a lot of "interpolation" methods..

Comment: Perhaps you should have a class for the particle system, a class for the particle and a class hierarchy for interpolation methods. The particle system can maintain a reference to the current interoplation method and provides it with particles to update. The interpolation method class operates on the particles via an interface (IParticle). This allows you to abstract the interpolation method away from the interpolated objects.

Comment: @gareththegeek: could be an answer